# QGIS GEarthView plugin ReactorAlreadyInstalledError

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error

I've been battling to get this really handy plugin working for some time. When I try installing it from plugin manager, I get the following error:

> "This plugin is broken
>   'module' object has no attribute 'ReactorAlreadyInstalledError'"

I've just installed QGIS 2.8.1 64Bit on Windows 7 machine. Zope and Twisted libraries both installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the issue, can you try out this zip:

```
https://github.com/opengisch/gearthview/archive/master.zip
```

I created a pull request, and I suppost it will be integrated in the next release.
Cheers
Marco

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are on a Linux machine (or MacOSX ?)

BTW, if you are on a nonWindows machine, you need to recompile reactor.   To do this, go into plugin folder with a shell terminal  ( that is something like  .qgis2/python/plugins/gearthview/reactor/   and type:

python setup.py install

( I do not remember if it is needed also the word "reactor" , so please try if it works, and report it here :)